# Embedding Facebook page in to an ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Hello fellow members,

I am currently developing an app which needs to have a Facebook page embedded inside it I have looked at the Facebook SDK and cannot seem to find a way of doing this.

Any suggestions or thoughts on this would be really appreciated

Thanks

Tom

Comment: As in a facebook page from the facebook website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a UIWebView in there and load an NSURL inside of it, with the URL being the address of your page.